# Array with repeated items

Tags: powershell, nested-loops

i am looking for logic to implement. I am having two arrays one array is having `$a=@(a1,b1,c1,d1,e1)` and `$b=@(1..100)`

```
$b=@('1'..'100')
$a=@('a1','b1','c1','d1','e1')
foreach($k in $a){
  foreach($j in $b){
     $j = $k
     Write-Host "The variable is :"$j" and the result is: "$k
  }
}
```

the output is:-

```
The variable is : 1 and the result is: 1
The variable is : 1 and the result is: 1
The variable is : 1 and the result is: 1
The variable is : 1 and the result is: 1
The variable is : 1 and the result is: 1
The variable is : 2 and the result is: 2
The variable is : 2 and the result is: 2
The variable is : 2 and the result is: 2
The variable is : 2 and the result is: 2
The variable is : 2 and the result is: 2
The variable is : 3 and the result is: 3
The variable is : 3 and the result is: 3
The variable is : 3 and the result is: 3
The variable is : 3 and the result is: 3
The variable is : 3 and the result is: 3
The variable is : 4 and the result is: 4
The variable is : 4 and the result is: 4
The variable is : 4 and the result is: 4
The variable is : 4 and the result is: 4
The variable is : 4 and the result is: 4
The variable is : 5 and the result is: 5
The variable is : 5 and the result is: 5
The variable is : 5 and the result is: 5
The variable is : 5 and the result is: 5
The variable is : 5 and the result is: 5
The variable is : 6 and the result is: 6
The variable is : 6 and the result is: 6
The variable is : 6 and the result is: 6
The variable is : 6 and the result is: 6
The variable is : 6 and the result is: 6
The variable is : 7 and the result is: 7
```

Actually the output should be the below:-

```
a1=1, b1=2, c1=3, d1=4, e1=5 again a1=6,b1=7,c1=8,d1=9, e1=10....a1=96,b1=97,c1=98,d1=99,e1=100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce the desired output as in your question (an array of 20 comma-separated lists of repeating name-value pairs with a steadily increasing sequence number):

```
$a = 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1'
$i = 0 # sequence number
foreach ($pass in 1..20) {
  $(foreach ($el in $a) {
    ++$i
    "$el=$i"
  }) -join ', '
}
```

This yields:

```
a1=1, b1=2, c1=3, d1=4, e1=5
a1=6, b1=7, c1=8, d1=9, e1=10
a1=11, b1=12, c1=13, d1=14, e1=15
a1=16, b1=17, c1=18, d1=19, e1=20
a1=21, b1=22, c1=23, d1=24, e1=25
a1=26, b1=27, c1=28, d1=29, e1=30
a1=31, b1=32, c1=33, d1=34, e1=35
a1=36, b1=37, c1=38, d1=39, e1=40
a1=41, b1=42, c1=43, d1=44, e1=45
a1=46, b1=47, c1=48, d1=49, e1=50
a1=51, b1=52, c1=53, d1=54, e1=55
a1=56, b1=57, c1=58, d1=59, e1=60
a1=61, b1=62, c1=63, d1=64, e1=65
a1=66, b1=67, c1=68, d1=69, e1=70
a1=71, b1=72, c1=73, d1=74, e1=75
a1=76, b1=77, c1=78, d1=79, e1=80
a1=81, b1=82, c1=83, d1=84, e1=85
a1=86, b1=87, c1=88, d1=89, e1=90
a1=91, b1=92, c1=93, d1=94, e1=95
a1=96, b1=97, c1=98, d1=99, e1=100
```

Note the use of expandable string `"$el=$i"` to produce each name-value pair.

In each pass, the pairs are collected by the `$(...)` around the inner `foreach` loop, which `-join` then converts into a comma-separated list (a single string); the output from the outer `foreach` loop is an array that contains the 20 lists.

If you want a *single* list with all entries instead, wrap the `$(...) -join ', '` around the *outer* `foreach` loop instead.

---

As for what you tried:

- `$j = $k` doesn't output an (expanded) string, it is a variable assingment: it assigns the value of variable `$k` to variable `$j`.
- You don't need `@(...)` around array literals.
- `'1'..'100'` is the same as `1..100` - if you specify *strings* as the the range endpoints, they are coerced to `[int]` values.

  - Note that PowerShell *Core* now also lets you create *character* ranges; e.g., `'a'..'z'`; in the rare event that you want to use a character that happens to be a digit, use a `[char]` cast to prevent its coercion to `[int]`; e.g, `[char] '1'.. [char] '3'`.

Comment: Glad to hear the answer was helpful, @kranthi; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

The expected output repeats $a while steadily incrementing from 1..100,
so nested loops aren't the way to achieve that.

Iterating `$b` and calculating the index into $a with a modulus division by the length/count of $a (and subracting one due to the zero based index) will do.

```
$b=@(1..100)
$a=@('a1','b1','c1','d1','e1')
($b|ForEach-Object {
    "{0}={1}" -f $a[($_ % $a.count)-1],$_
}) -join ', '
```

Sample output:

```
a1=1, b1=2, c1=3, d1=4, e1=5, a1=6, b1=7, c1=8, d1=9, e1=10, a1=11, b1=12, c1=13, d1=14, e1=15, a1=16, b1=17, c1=18, d1=19, e1=20, a1=21, b1=22, c1=23, d1=24, e1=25, a1=26, b1=27, c1=28, d1=29, e1=30, a1=31, b1=32, c1=33, d1=34, e1=35, a1=36, b1=37, c1=38, d1=39, e1=40, a1=41, b1=42, c1=43, d1=44, e1=45, a1=46, b1=47, c1=48, d1=49, e1=50, a1=51, b1=52, c1=53, d1=54, e1=55, a1=56, b1=57, c1=58, d1=59, e1=60, a1=61, b1=62, c1=63, d1=64, e1=65, a1=66, b1=67, c1=68, d1=69, e1=70, a1=71, b1=72, c1=73, d1=74, e1=75, a1=76, b1=77, c1=78, d1=79, e1=80, a1=81, b1=82, c1=83, d1=84, e1=85, a1=86, b1=87, c1=88, d1=89, e1=90, a1=91, b1=92, c1=93, d1=94, e1=95, a1=96, b1=97, c1=98, d1=99, e1=100
```

To not use the heavy handed pipe, a for should be faster

```
$a=@('a1','b1','c1','d1','e1')
$output = for ($b=1;$b -le 100;$b++){"{0}={1}" -f $a[($b % $a.count)-1],$b}
$output -join ', '
```